# Django can't update a related model field based on another model field in Database

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

Hello everyone I'm trying to update one of the table CashAdmin from fields cash_user based on my table PickUp based on fields is_finished and user as the foreign Key. But for some reason is not working.

This is the code:
Model of PickUp
model.py

```
from gc import is_finalized
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PickUp(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_finished = models.BooleanField   (default=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Model of CashAdmin
model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CashAdmin(models.Model):
    cash_user  = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The is the views file for PickUp.
views.py

```
from multiprocessing import context
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from pickup.forms import CreatePenjemputanForm
from pickup.models import PickUp
from cash.models import CashADmin
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
import datetime
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from PickUp.decorators import admin_only
# Create your views here.

def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'

@admin_only
def update_pickup(request, id):
    pick_up = PickUp.objects.get(pk=id)
    if pick_up.is_finished:
        pick_up.is_finished = False
    else:
        pickup.is_finished = True
        cash_user = pickup.quantity * 12500 if pick_up.is_finished else cash_user
        cash_admin, created = CashAdmin.objects.get_or_create(user=pick_up.user)
        cash_admin.cash_user = cash_admin.cash_user + cash_user
        cash_admin.save()
    pick_up.save()
    return redirect('pick_up:show_pick_up')
```

So in here I already created the code to update value fields of cash_user based on is_finished and from foreignKey of user. but the only thing that update is is_finished but the value of fields cash_user from CashAdmin just won't update. I don't know what is wrong.
Is it the syntax or intended or the logic of the code.
Can someone help me?

Comment: `pick_up.is_finished` does not make sense in `...ty * 12500 if pick_up.is_finished else ...` as you will skip the whole else block since `pick_up.is_finished` is true. Furthermore, you have two `users` fields in `PickUp` model and `cash_user` in `...d else cash_user` does not make sense as the variable does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

The first error I spotted is that, you have two `user` fields in your `PickUp` model.

The second error is that, you have set `pickup.is_finished = True` when the else clause is met. So all those block of code below `pickup.is_finished = True` in the else clause are running under `pickup.is_finished` conditions.

Thus: the line `cash_user = pickup.quantity * 12500 if pick_up.is_finished else cash_user` will always evaluate to `cash_user = pickup.quantity * 12500`.
So the part `... if pickup.is_finished else cash_user` is not really doing anything.

I do not really get the logic and what you are trying to achieve, but I think you may want to shift back the whole block of code below where you set `pickup.is_finished = True`.
This is what I mean:

```
...
else:
    pickup.is_finished = True
cash_user = pickup.quantity * 12500 if pick_up.is_finished else cash_user
cash_admin, created = CashAdmin.objects.get_or_create(user=pick_up.user)
cash_admin.cash_user = cash_admin.cash_user + cash_user
cash_admin.save()
pick_up.save()
return redirect('pick_up:show_pick_up')
```

This might solve the problem but if it doesn't, then you might have to rethink the logic.
If I knew exactly what you want to achieve from that logic, I could have provided a better solution for you. I hope this can help.

Comment: Hello, So I have 2 table in my database which is PickUp with fields (User, Quantity, is_finished) and CashAdmin with fields (cash_user, user). So if Pickup fields is_finished which is True I wanna update table on CashAdmin of the fields cash_user and times with quantity of the table PickUp fields with Quantity and update the value base if is_finished is true and times the value of quantity from PickUp and give value to  table CashAdmin of fields cash_user.

Comment: What is the reason behind the part:                                                                                 
        `if pick_up.is_finished: pick_up.is_finished = False`